# Get a Done list with doxygen

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

It is well known how to obtain a TODO list in Doxygen, typing:

```
\todo Item one
\todo Item two
```

and so on, but when something has been done, how to keep track of this?

If I have done item two I don't want to remove it, I want to mark it as done:

```
\todo Item ono
\done Item two
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug around in the Doxygen documentation and stumbled over the [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem). It's supposed to be:

> A generalization of commands such as \todo and \bug. It can be used to
>   create user-defined text sections which are automatically
>   cross-referenced between the place of occurrence and a related page,
>   which will be generated. On the related page all sections of the same
>   type will be collected.
>
> The first argument  is an identifier uniquely representing the
>   type of the section. The second argument is a quoted string
>   representing the heading of the section under which text passed as the
>   fourth argument is put. The third argument (list title) is used as the
>   title for the related page containing all items with the same key. The
>   keys "todo", "test", "bug" and "deprecated" are predefined.

So you could specify a new alias, e.g. `"done"` in your Doxyfile:

> ALIASES += "done=\xrefitem done \"Implemented TODOs\" \"Implemented
>   TODOs\" "

And in your code you should be able to use the new `"done"` tag like all the others:

> /// \done fixed broken function

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtodo) there is no such "inverse" of the `\todo` command. Perhaps you can just keep the `\todo` and mark it manually as done, somehow.

Unfortunately doxygen's Markdown doesn't seem to support <s>strikethrough</s> (unlike Stack Overflow's, obviously), that would otherwise have been a good and common choice. Perhaps you can set it up using custom styling and spans.